# How to bind an identifier with an existing symbol on a compiler transformer in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a typescript compiler transform using the typescript compiler API. However, when creating new Identifier nodes, even though the nodes get emitted to the final .js file, they seem to lack symbol binding information so the final output is incorrect.

Suppose I have the following program:

A.ts

```
export class A {
    static myMethod() {
        return 'value';
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
import { A } from './A';

export function main() {
    const value1 = 'replaceMe';
    const value2 = A.myMethod();
    const equals = value1 == value2;
}
```

Suppose I try to compile the above program with the following transformer:

```
function transformer(program: ts.Program): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> {
    return (context: ts.TransformationContext) => (file: ts.SourceFile) => transformFile(program, context, file);
}

function transformFile(program: ts.Program, context: ts.TransformationContext, file: ts.SourceFile): ts.SourceFile {
    const transformedFile = ts.visitEachChild(file, child => visit(child, context), context);
    console.log(ts.createPrinter().printFile(transformedFile));
    return transformedFile;
}
function visit(node: ts.Node, context: ts.TransformationContext): ts.Node {
    if (ts.isStringLiteral(node) && node.text == 'replaceMe') {
        return ts.createCall(
            ts.createPropertyAccess(
                ts.createIdentifier('A'),
                'myMethod'),
            [],
            []);
    }
    return ts.visitEachChild(node, child => visit(child, context), context);
}
```

The intermediate AST actually looks correct when pretty-printed:

```
import { A } from './A';

export function main() {
    const value1 = A.myMethod();
    const value2 = A.myMethod();
    const equals = value1 == value2;
}
```

But the output javascript is incorrect:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var A_1 = require("./A");
function main() {
    var value1 = A.myMethod();
    var value2 = A_1.A.myMethod();
    var equals = value1 == value2;
}
exports.main = main;
```

I understand this may be because by creating a new identifier with `ts.createIdentitier('A')`, this new identifier isn't bound to the same symbol as the other `A` identifier in the same file.

Is there a way to bind a new identifier to an existing symbol using the public compiler API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typescript compilation happens in phases (parsing, binding, type checking, emitting, a bit more detail [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Architectural-Overview)). You can use information form a previous phase but you can't typically change it. The transformations you can do during the emit phase are intended to allow you to bring the AST from Typescript to Javascript, not to refactor the code.

One way to accomplish your goal, would be to create the program, apply the transformations, and then create a new program with the modified code, reusing as much of the original program as possible (reuse the same `SourceFile` where no changes occurred)

```
function transformFile(program: ts.Program, file: ts.SourceFile): ts.SourceFile {
    let empty = ()=> {};
    // Dummy transformation context
    let context: ts.TransformationContext = {
        startLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        suspendLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        resumeLexicalEnvironment: empty,
        endLexicalEnvironment: ()=> [],
        getCompilerOptions: ()=> program.getCompilerOptions(),
        hoistFunctionDeclaration: empty,
        hoistVariableDeclaration: empty,
        readEmitHelpers: ()=>undefined,
        requestEmitHelper: empty,
        enableEmitNotification: empty,
        enableSubstitution: empty,
        isEmitNotificationEnabled: ()=> false,
        isSubstitutionEnabled: ()=> false,
        onEmitNode: empty,
        onSubstituteNode: (hint, node)=>node,
    };
    const transformedFile = ts.visitEachChild(file, child => visit(child, context), context);
    return transformedFile;
}

function visit(node: ts.Node, context: ts.TransformationContext): ts.Node {
    if (ts.isStringLiteral(node) && node.text == 'replaceMe') {
        return ts.createCall(
            ts.createPropertyAccess(
                ts.createIdentifier('A'),
                'myMethod'),
            [],
            []);
    }
    return ts.visitEachChild(node, child => visit(child, context), context);
}

let host = ts.createCompilerHost({});
let program = ts.createProgram(["toTrans.ts"], {}, host)

let transformed = program.getSourceFiles()
    .map(f=> ({ original: f, transformed: transformFile(program, f) }))
    .reduce<{ [name: string] : {original: ts.SourceFile, transformed: ts.SourceFile }}>((r, f)=> { r[f.original.fileName] = f; return r; }, {});

let originalGetSourceFile = host.getSourceFile;
let printer = ts.createPrinter();

// Rig the host to return the new verisons of transformed files.
host.getSourceFile = function(fileName, languageVersion, onError, shouldCreateNewSourceFile){
    let file = transformed[fileName];
    if(file){
        if(file.original != file.transformed){
            // Since we need to return a SourceFile it is tempting to return the transformed source file and not parse it again
            // The compiler doe not support Synthesized nodes in the AST except during emit, and it will check node positions 
            // (which for Synthesized are -1) and fail. So we need to reparse
            return ts.createSourceFile(fileName, printer.printFile(file.transformed), languageVersion);
        } else {
            // For unchanged files it should be safe to reuse the source file
            return file.original;
        }
    }
    return  originalGetSourceFile(fileName, languageVersion, onError, shouldCreateNewSourceFile);
}

// Recreate the program, we pass in the original to 
program = ts.createProgram(["toTrans.ts"], {}, host, program);

var result = program.emit();
```

Another way would be to use the language service and apply these changes through the language service, but honestly I have no experience with that part of the compiler and it seemed more complicated than this approach.

Comment: I was trying to avoid a second pass, but I guess in this case it has to be done this way. Very helpful information about different interfaces in the compiler API, thanks a lot. Do you know where I can find additional information about this stuff? (ie what's a lexical environment, hoist function declaration, etc..)

Comment: @PedroPedrosa The code above avoids the second pass for any non modified source files, for parsing at least. I don't have any good resources on the compiler internals, what I know, I know from reading github and the source code